# php rtrim until specific character

Tags: php, string, substr

I would like to do a sort of a rtrim on a string until a specific character like a " " (space)

input: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing el"

output: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing"

Tried several things but they all seem to work the other way around...

Thanks in Advance

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing el';
$strlen = strlen($string);
$length = strrpos($string, ' ');

if ($length === FALSE) {
  $length = $strlen;
}

$result = substr($string, 0, $length);
```

Comment: That did the trick... I did try strrpos but i thought it returned a string instead of a int, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$s =  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing el";
$s = preg_replace('/\s\S+$/i','',$s);
echo $s;
```

where `\s` is your *special char*

```
preg_replace('/^\S+\s/i','',$s); // is for ltrim analog
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a non regexp version:

```
function rTrimToChar($str,$char=" ") {
    return (strstr($str,$char)) ? substr($str,0,strrpos($str,$char)) : $str;
}

$str =  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing el";
echo rTrimToChar($str);
```